# Shared or sub UIViewController concept in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have (at least) two views which have the same table view but other stuff around, depending on how the user navigated in the app. Ideally, I would like to have a generic table view and controller which other views and controllers
could, for lack of a better term, "include". This would then allow me to encapsulate all the table view and controller logic within one file, so I don't have to duplicate code and logic between different views. Hopefully this question makes sense. How do achieve this?